# Pass two JSON object by web client post method C#

Tags: c#, post, webclient, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass below object as a parameter for a post method using web client method in C#.

```
     {
    "company":
    {
        "id": "e63dfcab345260b2591f585126ede56627db4ef2"
    },
    "requestor":
    {
        "id": "",
        "email": "customer@example.com ",
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "Requestor",
        "role": "employerAdmin",
        "phone": "(415)1112222",
        "title": "HR Manager"
    }
}
```

I converted like this

```
company[id]=e63dfcab345260b2591f585126ede56627db4ef2&requestor[id]=&requestor[email]=customer@example.com+&requestor[firstName]=Test&requestor[lastName]=Requestor&requestor[role]=employerAdmin&requestor[phone]=(415)1112222&requestor[title]=HR+Manager
```

But i am getting invalid parameter error. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

My entire code is below:

```
 using (var Requestor = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {

                string url = "https://stormaas-pre.inflection.com:8443/v1/Requestor?";
                string parameters = "company[id]='757563a3-67df-4a6e-9ef9-d89d57d41e0d'&requestor[id]=''&requestor[email]='customer@example.com'&requestor[firstName]='Test'&requestor[lastName]='Requestor'&requestor[role]='employerAdmin'&requestor[phone]='(415)1112222'&requestor[title]='HRManager'";
                Requestor.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
                Requestor.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz:xyz!", "");
                Requestor.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                Requestor.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                Requestor.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/xml";
                string res = Requestor.UploadString(url, "POST", parameters);
            }
```

Comment: Could you include more information such as the post target and how its being posted

Comment: Which version of .net framework are you using?

Comment: Using 4.5 and MVC  version 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create POCO classes for the Requestor, Company like follows and use JSON.net to do the conversion for you.

```
public class Company
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}

public class Requestor
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}

public class Container
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }

    public Requestor Requestor { get; set; }
}

var requestor = new Container();
requestor.Company = new Company { Id = "sampleid" };
requestor.Requestor = new Requestor
{
    FirstName = "test",
    LastName = "testname"
};

JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestor, settings);

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
// Code for the credentials etc
client.UploadString(@"your url", data);
```

Hope this helps. For this to work, you need to have a reference to JSON.net. Since you are using .net 4.5 with Web API, you should be having the reference already.

Answer (score 0):

You get invalid parameter error because square bracket are not allowed in a url. If you want use characters that are not include in [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) you must use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("String")`(msdn [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Ok! How to convert these two sub object into query string.

Comment: Getting same error from API. Please see this link https://www.goodhire.com/api-documentation#http