# How to send multiple parameters to a Web API call using WebClient

Tags: c#, json, post, webclient

I want to send via POST request two parameters to a Web API service. I am currently receiving 404 not found when I try in the following way, as from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0d3595k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static void PostString (string address)
{
    string data = "param1 = 5 param2 = " + json;
    string method = "POST";
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    string reply = client.UploadString (address, method, data);

    Console.WriteLine (reply);
}
```

where `json` is a json representation of an object. This did not worked, I have tried with query parameters as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp) but the same 404 not found was returned.

Can somebody provide me an example of WebClient which sends two parameters to a POST request?

Note: I am trying to avoid wrapping both parameters in the same class only to send to the service (as I found the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874156/pass-two-json-object-by-web-client-post-method-c-sharp))

Comment: It looks like you're trying to combine url encoded parameters with a stringified json object. That won't work.

Comment: @mituw16 yes, I tried to combine a url encoded parameter with a stringified json, and that did not worked, but how can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to either have all stringified JSON or have all url encoded parameters.

Comment: @meJustAndrew, Show target Web api end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to send both a json object and a simple value parameter by sending the simple parameter in the address link and the json as body data:

```
public static void PostString (string address)
{
    string method = "POST";
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();
    string reply = client.UploadString (address + param1, method, json);

    Console.WriteLine (reply);
}
```

Where address needs to expect the value parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sending your parameters as a [NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx).

Your code would look something like this when sending the parameters with a NameValueCollection:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            NameValueCollection requestParameters = new NameValueCollection();
            requestParameters.Add("param1", "5");
            requestParameters.Add("param2", json);
            byte[] response = client.UploadValues("your url here", requestParameters);
            string responseBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
        }
```

Using UploadValues will make it easier for you, since the framework will construct the body of the request and you won't have to worry about concatenating parameters or escaping characters.